# Receiving document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript, ajax

First let me say that I am new to javascript and ajax and I have searched this site and others for the answer but all suggestions do not work for me.  No matter what I do, readystate is always 0 and I always get an NULL exception on this line:
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

My goal is to use a dropdown box and select the name and return the associated email with it, which will be done in another file located on the same server and in the same directory.  But I cannot get past this point and I've been going nuts trying to figure out why this is happening.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var ajaxRequest;

function ajaxFunction(str)
{
  if ( str == "" )
  {
    document.getElementById("email").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    ajaxRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  { // code for IE6, IE5
    ajaxRequest=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if ( ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
    {
      if ( ajaxRequest.status==200) 
      {
        document.getElementById("email").innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
      }
    }
  }
  // Now get the value from user and pass it to server script.
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var queryString = "?email=" + email;

  queryString +=  "&title=" + title + "&usertype=" + usertype;
  ajaxRequest.open("GET", "file:///C:/ask.php" + queryString, true);
  ajaxRequest.send(null);

}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="POST">
  <select name="users" onchange="ajaxFunction(value)">
    <option value="">Select a person:</option>
    <option value="1">bill</option>
    <option value="2">ted</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="ajaxDiv"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no element with an `id` of `"email"`.  Why would you expect it to be anything but null?

Comment: Why did you tag this `jquery` if you aren't going to use any?

Comment: I removed the jquery tag.  Unsure why it was there to begin with.

Comment: I did add the element for email and it worked.  It is no longer giving me null.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any element with "email" id in your HTML code, so why should not be null? Simply not found. Define the element, same way you define another element with id `ajaxDiv`:

```
  <input id="email" type="text" value="email@sample.com">
```

Then you will be able to get the handle to this element and set the `value` property for it.

Comment: A `div` has no `value` property.

Comment: he is using `.innerHTML` to set value and then is trying to read the value using `.value`... and there is no element with `email` id...

Comment: Changed to `input` then. When no element, who could know which type it is supposed to be?

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use

```
var email = document.getElementById("email").innerHTML;
```

instead of

```
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
```

Comment: I tried both and neither has any effect on the null.  It was the fact that the element email was not defined as stated above.

Comment: it will never work if you do not have and element with `email` id

Comment: create a `div` with id `email` and try again